# Graceful way to handle when user refuse to enable required services

Tags: ios

I've been googling on how to gracefully handle when user refuse to enable  push notification service and location service that my app requires. I found out that Apple's human interface guideline prohibits developers from exiting app programatically and it should be left with users. But I don't want user to use my app without those services enabled since they are neccessary. How do accomplish that without violating any guidelines Apple laid out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would just display a static view that explains why those services are required and how the user can enable them - best by offering a button that will redirect to the settings (Swift 3 code):

```
// in Button handler code:
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(appSettings)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of apps implement a "pre-request" dialog, if the user accepts the request on the pre-request then display the actual permission request dialog as they're more likely to accept. If they decline your pre-request dialog, tell them again why you need the permissions or certain features won't function and try again. I haven't heard of Apple having any issues with this approach.

If they've already declined the permission request then you will need to alert them the required permissions haven't been granted and which features are now disabled, offer a dialog button to direct them to settings and display how to enable the permissions.

To open settings from your app use the below code

***Swift 3***

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

***Swift 2.x***

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

***Objective-C***

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]]
```

---

***Update***

Just realised you want to limit functionality of your app should user not have required services enabled. The best way is simply to push a view controller that displays an image and/or label stating that certain features aren't enabled and therefore the app can't function. You could detail the steps to enable required services with a button directing them to settings as per above. Again, I haven't seen Apple take issue with this as many apps implement this method should they lack for example GPS.